# Fail to load libraries after upgrading R to 3.6.0 on Mac

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I needed to install the R package `quadprog`, which only works for R with version 3.6.0. So I installed R (`3.6.0` version), and open it with `RStudio`. But now I **failed** to load any libraries, even after I installed the packages **successfully** using `install.packages("package_name")`. Specifically, the libraries I need to load are `caret`, `forecast` and `ggplot2`. I tried re-installing **R** but it still does not work. The error message I get is

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in
>   dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object
>   '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so,
>   6): Symbol not found: ___cxa_uncaught_exceptions   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libc++.1.dylib
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib  in
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libc++.1.dylib

After installing `Rcpp` package successfully with `install.packages("Rcpp")` , I still got the message above when I tried `library(Rcpp)`. So I am completely stumbled here...(before upgrades, everything works fine except I cannot install `quadprog`, so cannot install `forecast` package as well). Can anyone please help me fix this issue?

Please see below the images showing that the packages are stored in the same directory path of the `R.`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read that you need to recompile your old packages after upgrading to newer version of `R`. Run the following line in your `R` terminal

```
update.packages(ask=FALSE,
                checkBuilt=TRUE,
                repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

Then

```
install.packages(c("Rcpp", "caret", "forecast", "ggplot2", "quadprog"), 
                 dependencies=TRUE,
                 repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it out. But still ended up with the same error message (i.e, same as the very first one above) when trying to load `library(ggplot2)` or `library(caret)` or `library(forecast).` But it worked when I tried `library(lattice)` or `library(stats)` or `library(rpart).` So I guess the huge problem is due to unable to load `ggplot2`? Can you please help?

Comment: Restart RStudio then run `remove.packages(c("Rcpp", "caret", "forecast", "ggplot2", "quadprog")`. Delete any `000-Lock...` folders then run `install.packages` again

Comment: Where do you find the `000-Lock...` folders though? Are they in the `Resources` -> `lib` directory path?

Comment: Btw, when I do `remove.packages(c("Rcpp", "caret", "forecast", "ggplot2", "quadprog")`, I got this message: `Removing packages from ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified).` Is the last part about `lib` unusual?

Comment: Then what should I do now. I cannot find any folders named `000-Lock....` within the `R.framework` folder, or anywhere on my Mac.

Comment: If there is no `000-lock` folder then you're fine. Restart R and try everything again

Answer (score 5):

Had similar issue, restart R session and install Rcpp from source

`install.packages("Rcpp", type="source")`

then load the library

`library(Rcpp)`

if still getting the error, restart R session and try loading library again.

Comment: Thanks – I tried several other things that didn't work before this. First thought it was some Xcode-related problem.

Comment: Had similar problem attempting to loadi openxlsx.  This solution seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by getting and then google searching the exact error code :). I fixed it by installing the latest version of R from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) along with the latest version of [Rstudio](https://rstudio.com/). What I think happened was that when I updated some packages R and Rstudio were out of sync.